# Programmatically figure out if specific task in Task Scheduler is enabled

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008

I'd like to set up an automatic checker (for example a job in SQL Server) that would periodically check if specific task in Task Scheduler in Windows Server 2008 is enabled. The checker would then for example send an email if the task is disabled.

Is there any way of doing that?

Reason: sometimes your intent is to disable a task temporarily but you forget to enable it later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the Windows Task data via WMI.  I don't think SQL is the best answer to this question however -- I suppose you could write a CLR-Proc, but it would be better to write a .Net application and perhaps call that from SQL and handle the return code appropriately.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394601(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can check whether jobs are enabled using

```
 SELECT [name], [enabled] FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs;
```

But to periodically do that would require another job. What if that were disabled?

Comment: He wants SQL to poll the Windows Tasks, not the SQL jobs.